# RTOS in a virtual machine

Tags: linux, real-time, rtos

Are there any opensource/free Unix like RTOS that can run a virtual machine like QNX Neutrino RTOS (http://www.qnx.com/products/evaluation/eval-target.html)?

Comment: Do you need to run QNX (presumably a copy of QNX that you've purchased) in a virtual machine? Or are you looking for an OS to run some QNX programs? What are your realtime expectations — virtual machines make realtime difficult? If you want to run the evaluation version that you linked to, why not just install VirtualBox or VMWare on any of the Unix variants that they support?

Comment: I want to run an opensource or free OS like linux RTLinux. I wanted to know if someone who has tested something like this extensively and could recommend something because a lot of these OSes are not very stable even when run natively.

Comment: Ah, so you're looking for an alternative to QNX? Why the reference to a virtual machine: do you need real-time operation inside the VM? Usually real-time behavior is on real hardware, VMs are only for testing.

Comment: I first want to test it in a VM before my eventual goal is to have something like VxWin (http://www.acontis.com/eng/products/windows-real-time-hypervisor/vxwin/index.php) but with an open RTOS instead of VxWorks. So an OS that can work well in a VM would most likely be a better candidate than one that does not.

Answer (score 0):

RIOT is a good option. Its a microkernel based operating system highly designed for IoT applications. Few commands on your mac / linux terminal and you are into RIOT shell.

Please follow below links for more details:

- [RIOT-OS](https://riot-os.org/) : Their official Website
- [RIOT-on-Git](https://github.com/RIOT-OS/RIOT) : RIOT on github